# Importar un Array y trabajar con él después

Tags: java, array

A fin de mantener el código más limpio, se me ocurre establecer un array de `String` (ej. nombres de ciudades). Si deseara operar con este array para asignarle valores y luego ordenarlo en función de estos valores, ¿tendría que incluir todas estas operaciones en la clase desde la que importaré el array o Java me permite operar con él una vez importado?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] miArray = { "Tokio", "Moscú", "Paris" };
    myArray[0] = 5;
    myArray[1] = 8;
    myArray[2] = 3;
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los arreglos o arrays en Java no necesitan importarse, se pueden definir arreglos de cualquier tipo. Además, los arreglos son de tamaño estático, es decir, no permiten incrementar ni reducir su tamaño, por ende si declaras tu arreglo de 3 elementos entonces no puedes agregar un cuarto elemento o reducir su tamaño a 2 o menos.

Lo que buscas quizás es una lista [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) que utilice un arreglo para almacenar los datos, lo cual lo consigues con la clase [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Esta clase sí permite aumentar y reducir su tamaño conforme va creciendo en datos o reduciéndose. Lo otro que puedes hacer es iniciar una lista a partir de un arreglo. Basado en el ejemplo que provees, el código sería de esta manera:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listaCiudades = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Tokio", "Moscú", "Paris"));
    /*
      código comentado porque no tienen ningún sentido
      Java no es script, no es como JavaScript o Ruby
      donde los arreglos soportan cualquier tipo de dato
      a menos que definas tu arreglo como arreglo de objetos Object[]
    myArray[0] = 5;
    myArray[1] = 8;
    myArray[2] = 3;
    */
    Collections.sort(listaCiudades);
    System.out.println(listaCiudades);
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, en tal caso, si añado nuevos elementos y les asigno un valor, no sería necesario volver a dar valores a los elementos antiguos, ¿no? Bastaría con volver a emplear el método : 'Collections.sort(listaCiudades)'.

Comment: Exacto. Solo llamarías al método `add`, de esta manera: `listaCiudades.add("Lima");` y si luego quieres ordenarlos nuevamente usa el método `Collections#sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **static** para marcar una seccion de código como estático, esto te permite realizar operaciones de inicialización en atributos estáticos de una clase.

Además, si lo que deseas es mantener una lista invariable y disponible en cualquier otro punto de tu código te recomiendo que lo aisles, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, creo que esta es lo suficientemente correcta:

```
public class ListaCiudades {
  private static List<String> listaCiudades;

  static {
    listaCiudades = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Tokio", "Moscú", "Paris"));
  }

  public static List<String> sort() {
    Collections.sort(listaCiudades);
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(listaCiudades);
  }

}
```

Un problema adicional que puedes tener es que alguien añada o elimine elementos a la lista, para evitar esto utilizamos un método que permite que la lista sea inmutable, te adjunto test con su funcionamiento.

Este test verifica que la lista esta ordenada correctamente:

```
@Test
public void testListaOrdena() {
  List<String> listNoModificable=ListaCiudades.sort();

  assertThat(listNoModificable.get(0),is(equalTo("Moscú")));
  assertThat(listNoModificable.get(1),is(equalTo("Paris")));
  assertThat(listNoModificable.get(2),is(equalTo("Tokio")));

}
```

Este otro test te indica que si intentas añadir un elemento a la lista, no sea posible, garantizando así que la lista no puede ser modificada, produciendo una excepción de tipo **UnsupportedOperationException**:

```
@Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void testListaNoModificable() {
  List<String> listNoModificable=ListaCiudades.sort();
  listNoModificable.add("Lima");
}
```

Esto es solo una idea, se puede hacer de muchas otras formas.